# Pandas append() row concrete example

Tags: pandas

My question is how to cleanly append a row to a DataFrame by using DataFrame's append() method?

According to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), append() takes as a parameter a *"DataFrame or Series/dict-like object, or list of these".* Given the description, I thought something like this should be possible, but I can't find the right syntax:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('x', 'y', 'label'))
df.append([2, 4, 1]) # Does not work
```

I'm able to append a row with `df.loc[len(df)] = [4, 4, 1]` but this isn't very clean.

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't very clean".

Comment: Saying "add row" is easier to understand than saying "loc[len(df)]".

Answer (score 5):

With [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) need `Series` or `DataFrame` with same `index` or same `columns names` as `df`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 4, 1]], columns=('x', 'y', 'label'))
print (df1)
   x  y  label
0  2  4      1

df = df.append([pd.Series([4, 4, 1], index = df.columns)], ignore_index=True)
df = df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
#your solution
df.loc[len(df)] = [4, 4, 1]
print (df)
     x    y  label
0  4.0  4.0    1.0
1  2.0  4.0    1.0
2  4.0  4.0    1.0
```

---

```
#dont align because default columns names
df = df.append([[4, 4, 1]])
print (df)
     x    y label    0    1    2
0  NaN  NaN   NaN  4.0  4.0  1.0
```

But if default column names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(3))
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 1, 2]
Index: []

df = df.append([[4, 4, 1]])
print (df)
     0    1    2
0  4.0  4.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following as well:

```
df.loc[-1] = [4, 4, 1]
```

Really no way to have less than that.